# Can't bind to property since it isn't a known property of a component

Tags: angular

I have two folders inside app:

```
app/
├─ shared/
├─ main/
...
```

Each comprising their own module file.

I have imported shared module inside main module so that Shared components can be used in Main:

[image]

I have a **snack-bar** component inside Shared:

[image]

[image]

What I am trying to do is to take inputs from one of the Main folder components:

[image]

But then I get an error:

[image]

I am not sure where am I making mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add you shared module in `@NgModule({ imports: [SharedModule], })` of the main module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SnackBar` component should be declared and exported in `Shared` module.

```ts
@NgModule({
  // ...
  declarations: [ SnackBarComponent ],
  exports:      [ SnackBarComponent ],
  // ...
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

`Shared` module should be imported in `Main` module. (**In Angular way**)

```ts
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports:      [ SharedModule ],
  // ...
})
export class MainModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. Thanks zmag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `shared` module into the `main` module `imports` list. it's not enough to just reference it as an `import` at the top of the file. See the Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer! Inside Shared Module file, I forgot to put SnackBarComponent inside exports array:

[image]

Thanks for the answers.